# Where are the fields documented for the unicode.org file "UnicodeData.txt"?

Tags: unicode

I cannot find documentation for the actual fields of the UnicodeData.txt file.

The data is [available here](http://www.unicode.org/Public/5.1.0/ucd/). The document describing it is [available here](http://www.unicode.org/Public/5.1.0/ucd/UCD.html) but it doesn't list the actual field numbers and what the field is (like used to be in the document around [version 3.0](http://www.unicode.org/Public/3.0-Update/UnicodeData-3.0.0.html)).

I've searched the site and must be missing something that is right in front of my eyes, but I can't find it.

Can someone point out where this information is now?

Comment: https://unicode.org/ucd/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**update**

sorry, I misread the question. Still, I think the information is in the link you provided, under section [UnicodeData.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/5.1.0/ucd/UCD.html#UnicodeData.txt). For each field, a link inside the document lists its values if applicable. Seems to be the same list as in the 3.0 version.

Comment: That's the info for UniHan.txt but I am after the field info for UniData.txt

Comment: Hmm. You're right, it actually is the data I was after. I looked right at it and didn't see it. Probably because it skips the character field 0, and doesn't note the field numbers as obviously as the old version did. Thanks.

Comment: This is just the answer I was looking for, too. I think the Unicode documentation should be improved to make this much clearer.

Comment: Note the link above is for v5.1 of the UCD.  That file is obsolete in later versions and is replaced by:  http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#UnicodeData.txt

Comment: update: the latest revised link is - https://www.unicode.org/Public/9.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt

Comment: I think using the "latest" link would be best: https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/

Comment: I think using the "latest" link would be best: unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest as it gives you the root to all the necessary information to handle Unicode. The link by mcmcc unicode.org/reports/tr44/#UnicodeData.txt is actually still part of that (v13.0.0 at the moment—although they are already working on 14.0.0 and it has some 1,000 new characters in there already...).